# What are the common / noteworthy uses of meta programming in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, web, metaprogramming

I've been working with Ruby and many of it's web frameworks for about a year now.

I am aware that rails is built largely using 'meta-programming'. And while I have tried to inspect the source, often not all of it makes sense.

I tried to publish a small gem, and used a few methods like `_send`, `instance_eval`, `class_eval` which was cool but as a general principle we are told to stay far away from `eval` in it's various forms.

Other programming constructs I know where I can use. Like data serialization in applications or where I can / should implement the Builder Pattern when making web apps.

My question is in two parts:

1. What are the common or apt use cases / programming problems for which meta-programming is used?
2. When using the meta-programming bits of ruby, what are the best practices that I should follow?

Comment: [This presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1MJh4VhrKM) by Steven Harms is well worth watching.

Comment: Metaprogramming is so integral to ruby that you probably do it on a regular basis without even realizing it.  Methods that define methods? `eval` in all its forms?  It's everywhere in ruby.

Comment: @ZachKemp +1 for that video mate - was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever used `attr_accessor`? Then you have used metaprogramming: it is a method that generates methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that meta-programming is largely the domain of library APIs. Often you won't use much of it directly when creating an end-user application. But you can be sure, the many gems your application depends upon do use it extensively. Rails is a perfect example. It uses a great deal of Ruby's meta-programming chops to make all that Rails magic possible.